# Highlight duplicate value from second instance with red color , from hole sheet range(UsedRange)

Tags: excel, vba

I tried with below macro code but its not highlighting duplicate from 2nd instance Plz help me out

And one more thing iam trying to do with Dynamically not taking fixed range  (Particular range)

```
Sub FindingDuolicate()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim rngCell As Variant
    Dim Flag As Long
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Flag = 0
    For Each Rng In Selection
        If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, Rng.Value) > 1) Then
            Rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Flag = Flag + 1
        Else
            Rng.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next
    If Flag > 0 Then
        MsgBox Flag & " Cells (in red) Contain an Duplicate Data. Please Check"
    Else
        MsgBox " Data Validation Completed . No Duplicate Found. "
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Flag as Long` (not `Dim LR`);  and `xlNone` not `x1None` (L not 1).

Comment: @A.S.H  sorry that is typing mistakes , i corrected that . But i need help plz help me if  u can

Comment: Your macro worked for me with the above corrections, although didn't test it hardly. How are you invoking it? Also add `Option Explicit` it is very useful to help you spot many errors.

Comment: @A.S.H yes its working but that code highlighting all duplicates , but i want to highlight duplicate from second instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could turn your sub into a function:

```
Function FindingDuplicate(rng As Range, counter As Long) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rng(1, 1), cell), cell.Value) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
            cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next
    FindingDuplicate = counter > 0
End Function
```

to be exploited by your "main" sub as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim counter As Long

    If FindingDuplicate(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, counter) Then '<--| change 'ActiveSheet.UsedRange' to whatever range you want
        MsgBox counter & " cells (red background) contain a duplicated data. Please Check"
    Else
        MsgBox " Data Validation Completed. No Duplicate Found."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for ur help

Comment: the code which you sended me , that macro code is not working on string and three digits numbers ex:- 444

Comment: I tested it with such a cell content as "- 444" and it worked formatted both as a "text" and as a "number"

Comment: Hi , in msgbox how can we get duplicate cell value and how should we say that duplicate value repeated particular time 
Example :- Duplicate cell value is 22 and 22 duplicated 2 times

Comment: in `FindingDuplicate()` inside `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rng(1, 1), cell), cell.Value) > 1 Then` clause you have to collect current `cell.Value` in some way (a string, to be updated at every duplicate occurrence, or an array) and return it to the caller (then you have to add the string/array among function _parameters_) that will be able to _read_ and show it in a MsgBox

Comment: i add the Cellvalue As String and collecting the cell.value in it , how to use it in Main() msgbox  plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer.  It now doen't use countif but loops through each previous cell to make a comparison.  COULD BE SLOW IF YOU HAVE A VERY LARGE RANGE but it does work on multiple columns.

```
Sub DupsCheck()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RngChecked As Range
Dim previousRng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim LR As Long

'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Flag = 0

Selection.Interior.Pattern = x1None

For Each Rng In Selection
    If Not RngChecked Is Nothing Then
    ' Add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc cell to our new range, rng2
    ' this is the most common outcome so place it first in the IF test (faster coding)

    For Each previousRng In RngChecked

        If previousRng.Value = Rng.Value And Rng.Interior.Color <> vbRed Then
        Debug.Print previousRng.Address & " " & Rng.Address
            Rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Flag = Flag + 1

        End If
        'Debug.Print Flag
    Next

        Set RngChecked = Union(RngChecked, Rng)
    Else
    ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
        Set RngChecked = Rng
    End If

Next
If Flag > 0 Then
    MsgBox Flag & " Cells (in red) Contain an Duplicate Data. Please Check"
Else
    MsgBox " Data Validation Completed . No Duplicate Found. "
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yes its working i knw but i need it will be highlight from 2nd instance , plz help me

Comment: I knew you wanted that so I've just updated my answer.

Comment: If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngChecked, rng.Value) > 1) Then                               getting error in above line run-time '5'        invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Yes i executed jst now but getting run-time error '5'

Comment: did you add the code above (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngChecked, rng.Value) > 1) . Also I forgot to put Dim RngChecked As Range at the top.

Comment: Yes i add this before only Dim Rngchecked As Range at the Top , error is coming on this line only If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngChecked, rng.Value) > 1

Comment: It works for me but I have to comment out ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select for some reason. try and copy all my code again, I edited it so it's a sub called HighlightDups

Comment: its work fine on A1 ,B1,C1,D1,E1 soon till XFD1 . when come to A2  it will through the error 1004  Unable to get the CountIf property of the worksheetFunction class

Comment: you didn't specify that you wanted it to check a range larger than a simple 1 column list.  The answer you accepted doesn't work for a range with multiple columns either and I haven't worked out why mine doesn't yet.

Comment: just updated my answer so it now doen't have to use countif as countif can't handle complex ranges.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that Multiple columns and thnk u for helpng me ur great man